# need the steps on how to do this recurrence relation question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Given $T_0=0 $ and $T_n=T_{n−1}+n \forall n\in \mathbb N$ use the method of substitution to derive an explicit formula for $T_n$. Prove the validity if your formula.

Comment: What have u tried?

Comment: i am completely lost...dont know how to start

Comment: Start with $T_1 = T_0 + 1 = 1$, then $T_2 = T_1 + 2 = \dots$. Write out a couple more, and see if it helps you make sense of what $T_n$ is --- you should be able to recognise it from there.

Comment: Use the method of successive differences

Answer (score 1):

If $T_n = T_{n-1} + n$, then $T_{n-1} = T_{n-2} + (n-1)$, so actually
$\color{}{T_n = T_{n-2} + n+(n-1).}$

But I lied, $T_{n-2} = T_{n-3} + (n-2)$. So actually, $\color{}{T_n = T_{n-3} + n + (n-1) + (n-2).}$

Continuing this till $T_{n-n} = T_0$, we have,

$$T_n = T_0 + \sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

---

Now we have to prove that this result is valid. We do this by induction on $n$.

For $n=0$, we have $T_0 = 0$. Assume for some fixed $n$, that $T_n= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. 
From the recurrence, we know that $T_{n+1} = T_{n} + (n+1)$. But by the inductive hypothesis, we have 
$$T_{n+1} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + (n+1) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}.$$
So, by mathematical induction, our formula satisfies the recurrence relation $T_n = T_{n-1} + n$.